# mod rewrite QUERY_STRING issue

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

All,

I am redirecting some urls with specific query strings to new page . For example `http://testserver.xyz.com/abc/content/content.jsp?contentId=123` or `http://testserver.xyz.com/abc/content/content.jsp?contentId=345` needs to be redirected to `http://ww2.newtestserver.com/xyz.html`

For this purpose i wrote following redirects:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} contentId=123 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} contentId=345 [OR] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} contentId=678 
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://ww2.newtestserver.com/xyz.html/? [R=301,L]
```

This works fine except when i type in my browser `http://testserver.xyz.com/abc/content/content.jsp?contentId=1234`. This also gets redirected to `http://ww2.newtestserver.com/xyz.html`.

I do not want this. how can i prevent this so that my mod rewrite only looks at query    string 123 or 345 or 567 but not something 123x or 345x or 678x?

Please help

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure that the rewrite looks only at the exact query strings you specified, you should tell it that those are the *full* query strings using `^` and `$`. `^` matches the beginning of the string, and `$` matches the end.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^contentId=123$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^contentId=345$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^contentId=678$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://ww2.newtestserver.com/xyz.html [R=301,L]
```

The above code will work. The code below might work (and should be more efficient), but I'm not at a computer I can test on right now.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^contentId=(123|345|678)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://ww2.newtestserver.com/xyz.html [R=301,L]
```